# what is the meaning of m.rng ? in the code

Tags: java

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class ElGamal1 {

           SecureRandom  rng = new SecureRandom();
     public static void main(String[] args)      {      
      try {            
            System.out.println("ElGamal::main");    
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); 

            ElGamal1 m = new ElGamal1();
            System.out.println("Do you want to generate new keys (y/n)? +m.rng);
            String generateKeys = s.next();
----------
----------
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*m* is an instance of *ElGamal1* which you created in your main method by calling

```
ElGamal1 m = new ElGamal1();
```

while *r* is a field (or attribute) of this instance of type *SecureRandom*. If you call

```
            System.out.println("Do you want to generate new keys (y/n)? " +m.rng);
```

this will just execute the toString method of *SecureRandom* which will generate something like 'java.security.SecureRandom@57ad85ed' which is quite useless (in my eyes).

Does that answer your question?